# for loop count number of terms java

Tags: java, for-loop

Hey guys i'm stuck on count for a for loop... It should be easy, but for some reason i'm over thinking it or something!
Any help would be awesome!

i'm trying to get the total number of terms that passed through %2 and print them out, but when i try it my way it does 11223344556677889910 which i thought was weird! all i want to do is get to say (10).

```
int counter = 0 

for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 1) {
        counter += 1;
    }
    System.out.print(counter);
}
```

output is 112233445566778899

can't use arrays or lists :\

Comment: Please show the full code, because what you have doesn't compile.

Comment: I strongly recommend learning to use a debugger.

Comment: Just a note, you really need to clarify that `pass through %2`. Someone might understand that pass through means the remainder of i%2 is not 0 and someone else might think it is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` condition seems incorrect, try with: (EDIT: start `counter` with 1 and move SOP out of `for` loop)

```
int counter = 1 

for(int i=1;i<20;i++) {
if (i%2==0) //Match for 2
{ 
  counter+=1;
}
}
System.out.print(counter);
```

Comment: "Match for 2", `%` is the modulo operator, which calculates the remainder of the Euclidean division of a by b

Comment: great it worked! thank you man! thought i tried that but i guess not! really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the counter outside of for loop `System.out.print(counter);`  and looks like  i%2==1 is not correct. You need to change to i%2==0

```
int counter = 0 

for(int i=1;i<20;i++) {
     if (i%2==0)
     {
         counter+=1;
     }
}
System.out.print(counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

System.out.print is inside your for loop, it's printing each iteration.

If you want 10, move the call to .print() outside the for loop, and start your counter at 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

The output is correct in this case. You are printing the total amount of `counter` every time the loop is executed. So for i=0 that would be counter=1, for i=1 that would be still counter=1, for i=2 the counter increases to 2, for i=3 the counter remains 2 which is printed etc.

The code is working correctly but there is a fault in it. Move the `System.out.print(counter);` outside of the `for` loop and it should work correctly. Also remember to initialize your `counter` to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Take the `print` line out of the `for loop`, or else it will print the count every iteration (obviously), which is 19 times.

```
int counter = 0;

for(int i = 1; i < 20; i++) 
{
    if (i % 2 == 1) counter++;
}
System.out.print(counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put `System.out.print(counter);` inside the for loop. That's the reason. This will work:

```
int counter = 0; 
for(int i=1;i<20;i++) {
    if (i%2==1)
    { 
        counter+=1;
    }       
}
System.out.print(counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print(counter);
```

You should put this line of code outside the for loop to avoid printing out each value of `counter`.